# Upload & Download speed in Tmux status line

Tags: tmux

Is there a way to get upload and download speeds in Tmux's status line?

Answer (score 7):

You can call a shell script from tmux's status line, specifying your required interface like so:

```
set -g status-left '#[fg=blue]#(speed eth0)#[default]'
```

And place this script, speed<sup>1</sup>, in your $PATH:

```
#!/bin/bash

iface=$1
RXB=$(</sys/class/net/"$iface"/statistics/rx_bytes)
TXB=$(</sys/class/net/"$iface"/statistics/tx_bytes)
sleep 2 
RXBN=$(</sys/class/net/"$iface"/statistics/rx_bytes)
TXBN=$(</sys/class/net/"$iface"/statistics/tx_bytes)
RXDIF=$(echo $((RXBN - RXB)) )
TXDIF=$(echo $((TXBN - TXB)) )

echo -e "$((RXDIF / 1024 / 2))K/s $((TXDIF / 1024 / 2))K/s"
```

<sup>1. Can't remember where I found this...</sup>

Comment: Why do you read rx_bytes twice then take the difference and then divide by the amount you slept. exspecially why do divide by the sleeptime? or is this just coincidence?

Comment: Oh... now i see. we want to display Kb per >second<. because we measure how many bytes passed between the two measurements we have to divide by the sleeptime to calculate the Kb/s

Answer (score 2):

I wanted the answer above by jasonwryan to deal with all interfaces so I made this modification:

```
#!/bin/bash

RXB=0
TXB=0

for rxbytes in /sys/class/net/*/statistics/rx_bytes ; do
  let RXB+=$(<$rxbytes)
done

for txbytes in /sys/class/net/*/statistics/tx_bytes ; do
  let TXB+=$(<$txbytes)
done

sleep 2 

RXBN=0
TXBN=0

for rxbytes in /sys/class/net/*/statistics/rx_bytes ; do
  let RXBN+=$(<$rxbytes)
done

for txbytes in /sys/class/net/*/statistics/tx_bytes ; do
  let TXBN+=$(<$txbytes)
done    

RXDIF=$(echo $((RXBN - RXB)) )
TXDIF=$(echo $((TXBN - TXB)) )

echo -e "$((RXDIF / 1024 / 2))K/s $((TXDIF / 1024 / 2))K/s"
```

You can obviously change the wildcard to only do all eth* or wlan* interfaces, or use find to make a more complicated match of the two.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the Above, this should display up and down indicators using ^ and v, use the correct symbol (Ki is binary Kilobytes, etc) change to Mi and Gi as needed, and also display non zero fractional values of one decimal place.

https://github.com/gryftir/tmux-networkspeed